# Game rope swing physics acting weird

Tags: java, physics, game-physics

I'm trying to implement rope swinging in my platformer, following [this tutorial](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swinging-physics-for-player-movement-as-seen-in-spider-man-2-and-energy-hook--gamedev-8782). Instead of swing on the rope, the player looks like he's sliding down a slope: he moves very slowly towards the bottom.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: what it looks like now]

Instead, I want the player to have more natural movement, like he's really swinging on the rope.

This is the update method from my player class:

```
@Override
    public final void update() {
        setPosition(getNextPosition());
        if (direction == Direction.LEFT && moving) {
            getVelocity().x = -WALK_SPEED;
        } else if (getVelocity().x < 0) {
            getVelocity().x *= COEF_FRIC;
        }

        if (direction == Direction.RIGHT && moving) {
            getVelocity().x = WALK_SPEED;
        } else if (getVelocity().x > 0) {
            getVelocity().x *= COEF_FRIC;
        }

        checkAsleep();
        animations.update();

        if (ropePoint != null) {
            //getCenter() returns the center position of the player
            if (getCenter().toPoint().distanceSq(ropePoint) > ROPE_LENGTH * ROPE_LENGTH) {

                final Vec2D oldPosition = getCenter();
                final Vec2D oldVelocity = getVelocity();
                final Vec2D ropePosition = new Vec2D(ropePoint);

                setCenter((oldPosition.subtract(ropePosition).unit().multiply(ROPE_LENGTH).add(ropePosition)));
                setVelocity(oldPosition.subtract(getCenter()).unit().multiply(oldVelocity));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my implementation of `getNextPosition()`, if it is needed.

```
public final Vec2D getNextPosition() {

        final int currCol = (int) (getX() / Tile.SIZE);
        final int currRow = (int) (getY() / Tile.SIZE);

        final double destX = getX() + moveData.velocity.x;
        final double destY = getY() + moveData.velocity.y;

        double tempX = getX();
        double tempY = getY();

        Corners solidCorners = getCornersAreSolid(getX(), destY);
        boolean topLeft = solidCorners.topLeft;
        boolean topRight = solidCorners.topRight;
        boolean bottomLeft = solidCorners.bottomLeft;
        boolean bottomRight = solidCorners.bottomRight;

        framesSinceLastTopCollision += 1;
        framesSinceLastBottomCollision += 1;
        framesSinceLastLeftCollision += 1;
        framesSinceLastRightCollision += 1;
        if (moveData.velocity.y < 0) {
            if (topLeft || topRight) {
                moveData.velocity.y = 0;
                tempY = currRow * Tile.SIZE;
                framesSinceLastTopCollision = 0;
            } else {
                tempY += moveData.velocity.y;
            }
        } else if (moveData.velocity.y > 0) {
            if (bottomLeft || bottomRight) {
                moveData.velocity.y = 0;
                tempY = (currRow + 1) * Tile.SIZE - moveData.collisionBox.getHeight() % Tile.SIZE - 1;
                framesSinceLastBottomCollision = 0;
            } else {
                tempY += moveData.velocity.y;
            }
        }

        solidCorners = getCornersAreSolid(destX, getY());
        topLeft = solidCorners.topLeft;
        topRight = solidCorners.topRight;
        bottomLeft = solidCorners.bottomLeft;
        bottomRight = solidCorners.bottomRight;
        if (moveData.velocity.x < 0) {
            if (topLeft || bottomLeft) {
                moveData.velocity.x = 0;
                tempX = currCol * Tile.SIZE;
                framesSinceLastLeftCollision = 0;
            } else {
                tempX += moveData.velocity.x;
            }
        }
        if (moveData.velocity.x > 0) {
            if (topRight || bottomRight) {
                moveData.velocity.x = 0;
                tempX = (currCol + 1) * Tile.SIZE - moveData.collisionBox.getWidth() % Tile.SIZE - 1;
                framesSinceLastRightCollision = 0;
            } else {
                tempX += moveData.velocity.x;
            }
        }
        return new Vec2D(tempX, tempY);
    }
```

What should I change in this code to get natural movement?

Comment: Looks cool. I would try moving the character a bit towards the center of the circle so the end of the rope is where his hands would be and not in his head. I'd also try rotating the character so he's always perpendicular to the rope. If you want to go further you can play around with things like elasticity and having the rope bend.

Comment: Is your concern to better model the acceleration?  Also, why does the player slow down and jitter as they get to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that the problem lies in that first if statement:
`if (direction == Direction.LEFT && moving) {
    getVelocity().x = -WALK_SPEED;
 } else if (getVelocity().x < 0) {
    getVelocity().x *= COEF_FRIC;
 }`
If the first thing is true, you're going to constantly be setting the velocity to walking pace, which doesn't make sense when your guy is swinging on a rope. He should be speeding up as he goes down and slowing down on the way up.
If the first thing is false, then since he is going left, you're definitely going to go into the else if statement, and he'll be slowed down by friction. I don't see where you set that, but it seems to still be the friction he has on the ground, which would seem to explain why he's all stuttery and looks more like he's sliding than falling.
You might want to add different states instead of just "moving", (perhaps jumping, swinging, walking, running, stopped) and vary how he behaves while doing each of those things.