# Unity rope swinging physics algorithm: Player stuck mid-swing

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I have implemented the following tutorial in Unity (2D) attempting to create a rope swinging platformer: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/swinging-physics-for-player-movement-as-seen-in-spider-man-2-and-energy-hook--gamedev-8782

```
void FixedUpdate() 
{
    Vector2 testPosition = playerRigidbody.position + playerRigidbody.velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    Hooked(testPosition);
}

private void Hooked(Vector2 testPosition)
    {
        Vector2 t = new Vector2(tetherPoint.position.x, tetherPoint.position.y);
        Debug.DrawLine(tetherPoint.position, playerRigidbody.position);
        float currentLength = (testPosition - t).magnitude;

        if (currentLength < tetherLength)
        {
           currentLength = (playerRigidbody.position - t).magnitude * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
            currentLength = tetherLength;

        if ((testPosition - t).magnitude > tetherLength)
        {
            Vector2 x = (testPosition - t).normalized;
            testPosition = new Vector2(x.x * currentLength, x.y * currentLength);

            playerRigidbody.velocity = (testPosition - playerRigidbody.position) * Time.deltaTime;
            playerRigidbody.position = testPosition;
        }
    }
```

It seems to function correctly on the downward swing but when the player begins to travel upwards they become stuck floating in the air and don't drop to the middle of the arc. The swing also does not propel them very high on the other side even when dropped from height.

EDIT (Further clarification): Interestingly When the player is dropped from the other side of the tetherPoint it stops in the same spot, this time only half-way down. It's as if the player is being pulled toward a single position even when manually moved in the editor while playing no matter the direction.

EDIT: User John cleared up my concerns about deltaTime.

I've tried examining the change in variables during play but I just can't figure out why it's not working correctly. I think the issue lies somewhere in my interpretation of the original psudeo-code to C#.

Another question on the same tutorial has been asked previously but unfortunately that users implementation was very different than mine: [Game rope swing physics acting weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456447/game-rope-swing-physics-acting-weird)

EDIT: Since posting I've updated the code to use AddForce and MovePosition instead but it's still the same.

```
playerRigidbody.AddForce((testPosition - playerRigidbody.position) * Time.deltaTime);
playerRigidbody.MovePosition(testPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `Time.deltaTime` from a method that is called from `FixedUpdate`. What you want to use instead is `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

`FixedUpdate` is called at a set interval (eg. 50fps) for physics updates, but regular `Update` is called at a different varying frequency (up to hundreds of times a second if you've got a fast computer/simple game).

`Time.deltaTime` is used for the `Update` method, and so the value of it can be different each time `Update` is called, as the time between `Update` calls varies.

However, because `FixedUpdate` is called at the same interval each time, `Time.fixedDeltaTime` is constant and (normally) much larger than `Time.deltaTime`. Your code doesn't work well with `Time.deltaTime`, as it doesn't represent the actual difference in time between each `FixedUpdate` call, but `Time.fixedDeltaTime` should work.

As a side note, <del>you're correct that you should be multiplying by the time delta rather than dividing.</del> the time delta should be multiplied when calculating positions (eg. for the `Vector2 testPosition` assignment and the `currentLength` calculation), but for calculating the velocity you should be dividing the time delta (because velocity = distance/time).

Comment: I didn't know this, thank you for the feedback :) Changing it to fixedDeltaTime did not fix the issue though, the player character still get's stuck halfway up the other side of the swing.

Comment: I just noticed that the last thing I wrote was wrong, and have edited my answer - I said you should always be multiplying the time delta - which was incorrect because at one point you're calculating the velocity, which should actually be distance/Time.fixedDeltaTime. Does that help fix the issue?

Comment: Sadly no, even with changing it to fixedDeltaTime and dividing instead of multiplying nothing changes. I've updated the post with some more info, it's as if the player is actually being pulled to that specific point for some reason.